# reCaptcha chrome security error - blocked a frame

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, recaptcha

I am running a ruby on rails application (https://www.recognitionnotes.com), on an amazon linux instance with an apache server.  reCaptcha had been working well for me for several weeks, but the most recent update (52.0.2743.82 m (64-bit)) possibly introduced a bug in the recaptcha for Chrome only.  Firefox (47.0.1) and even Internet explorer 8 are working well, all 3 browsers running Windows 7 64bit.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

In the Chrome JS console I get the following errors:

```
recaptcha__en.js:170 Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.recognitionnotes.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.xk.send 
    @ recaptcha__en.js:170f.kj 
    @ recaptcha__en.js:390f.init 
    @ recaptcha__en.js:385(anonymous function) 
    @ recaptcha__en.js:391(anonymous function) 
    @ VM2211 frame?c=…:183
```

In the Network console, here are the requests are being executed.

the First network request which seems to be successful:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/frame?c=...
general:
    Request URL:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/frame?c=...
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200 
    Remote Address:172.217.4.196:443

response headers:
    alt-svc:quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34,33,32,31,30"
    alternate-protocol:443:quic
    cache-control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    content-encoding:gzip
    content-length:10526
    content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
    date:Wed, 24 Aug 2016 14:44:12 GMT
    expires:Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
    pragma:no-cache
    server:GSE
    status:200
    x-content-type-options:nosniff
    x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
    request headers:
    :authority:www.google.com
    :method:GET
    :path:/recaptcha/api2/frame?c=...
    :scheme:https
    accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
    accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    dnt:1
    referer:https://www.recognitionnotes.com/
    upgrade-insecure-requests:1
    user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
```

Second Network request that seems to fail

```
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20160817124709/recaptcha__en.js
general:
    Request URL:https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20160817124709/recaptcha__en.js
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200  (from cache)
    Remote Address:172.217.4.67:443

response headers:
    age:76738
    alt-svc:quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34,33,32,31,30"
    alternate-protocol:443:quic
    cache-control:public, max-age=31536000
    content-encoding:gzip
    content-length:70976
    content-type:text/javascript
    date:Tue, 23 Aug 2016 17:24:39 GMT
    expires:Wed, 23 Aug 2017 17:24:39 GMT
    last-modified:Wed, 17 Aug 2016 20:15:00 GMT
    server:sffe
    status:200
    vary:Accept-Encoding
    x-content-type-options:nosniff
    x-xss-protection:1; mode=block

request headers:
    Provisional headers are shown
    Referer:https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/frame?c=...
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Why do you think that second request failed? Looks fine to me. It actually appears the frame has violated Same-Origin Policy by trying to access another frame from another origin.

Comment: I have a feeling that the request actually was successful `status 200`.  I also have a feeling that something is going wrong because the reCaptcha is inside of a modal.  As far as cross-origin-policy, I forgot to mention that I added the apache header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.google.com`